# How can I install a webextension in GeckoView

Tags: java, android, kotlin, geckoview

I want to install a Firefox extension in a GeckoView
I tried the instruction from the docu ().
My code:

```
val runtime = GeckoRuntime.create(this)
geckoSession.open(runtime)
geckoView.setSession(geckoSession)
runtime.getWebExtensionController().installBuiltIn("resource://android/assets/addonXY/")
```

The Problem is that getWebExtensionController() has no installBuiltIn() function.

Can someone help me show me how to install extensions in GeckView

Comment: Cross referencing to the same issue posted on github:
https://github.com/mozilla/geckoview/issues/176

Comment: What version of GeckoView are you using? installBuiltIn was introduced in 78: https://mozilla.github.io/geckoview/javadoc/mozilla-central/org/mozilla/geckoview/doc-files/CHANGELOG#v78